# Загрузка файлов на удаленный сервер

Tags: spring, java

Пользуюсь openshift сервером, развернул там свое spring приложение с maven. Для статических файлов использую прописанное в dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Я создал форму загрузки файлов на сервер.
В таком случае, когда я развертываю приложение на localhost, то сохраняя через

```
File file = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/")+"uploads/");
```

файлы сохраняются в место

```
myproject/src/main/resources/uploads
```

И это то, что мне надо.

Но на удаленном сервере создана специальная папка для загружаемых файлов, и она находится в

```
myproject/app-root/data/uploads
```

Я настроил приложение таким образом, что на удаленном сервере загружаемые файлы сохраняются по этому адресу, но просмотреть с браузера загруженные, например, изображения я не могу, поскольку, как я понимаю

```
<mvc:resources mapping
```

не настроена должным образом для данного случая. Как это можно изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено, нужно было изменить настройки в context.xml Apache 7   https://blog.openshift.com/multipart-forms-and-file-uploads-with-tomcat-7/

Answer (score 1):

[На StackOverflow говорят](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456635/spring-serving-static-resources-outside-context-root), что можно вот так:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="file:/full/path/to/myproject/app-root/data/uploads"/>
```

Если не заработает, то нужно писать свой сервлет, который бы раздавал статику (примеры есть в интернете, например [здесь](http://balusc.blogspot.ru/2007/04/imageservlet.html)).